# sql server: Is this nesting in a transcation sufficient for getting a unique number from the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

i want to generate a unique number from a table.
It has to be thread safe of course, so when i check for the last number and get '3', and then store '4' in the database, i don't want anybody else just in between those two actions (get the number and store it one higher in the database) also to get '3' back, and then also storing '4'

So i thought, put it in a transaction like this:

```
begin transaction
        declare @maxNum int
        select @maxNum = MAX(SequenceNumber) from invoice
            where YEAR = @year
        if @maxNum is null
        begin
            set @maxNum = 0
        end
        set @maxNum = @maxNum + 1
        INSERT INTO [Invoice]
           ([Year]
           ,[SequenceNumber]
           ,[DateCreated])
     VALUES
           (@year
           ,@maxNum
           ,GETUTCDATE()
)

    commit transaction

    return @maxNum
```

But i wondered, is that enough, to put it in a transaction?
my first thought was: it locks this sp for usage by other people, but is that correct? how can sql server know what to lock at the first step?

Will this construction guarantee me that nobody else will do the `select @maxnum` part just when i am `updating the @maxnum` value, and at that moment receiving the same @`maxnum` as i did so i'm in trouble.

I hope you understand what i want to accomplish, and also if you know if i did choose the right solution.

EDIT:
also described as 'How to Single-Thread a stored procedure'

Comment: And why - oh why - aren't you just simply using an `IDENTITY` column and leave all the nitty-gritty tough-as-nails work to SQL Server???

Comment: @marc_s: Prolly because the number must be reset each `YEAR`.

Comment: @GSerg: run a `DBCC CHECKIDENT(table, RESEED, 1)` once every January 1 and you're done....

Comment: good thoughts, but i want the seq number + year stored in the table. They are invoice numbers and must be stored for 10 years

Comment: but aren't computed columns recomputer everytime? i'm not sure how i can restart my counting at 1 the next year this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, i didn't want to lock the table, i just wanted to execute the stored procedure one at a  time. 
In C# code i would place a lock on another object, and that's what was discussed here
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic357663-8-1.aspx

So that's what i used

```
declare @Result int
EXEC @Result =
sp_getapplock @Resource = 'holdit1', @LockMode = 'Exclusive', @LockTimeout = 10000 --Time to wait for the lock
IF @Result < 0
BEGIN
ROLLBACK TRAN
RAISERROR('Procedure Already Running for holdit1 - Concurrent execution is not supported.',16,9)
RETURN(-1)
END
```

where 'holdit1' is just a name for the lock.
`@result` returns 0 or 1 if it succeeds in getting the lock (one of them is when it immediately succeeds, and the other is when you get the lock while waiting)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have the year and a sequence number stored in the database, and create an invoice number from that, I'd use:

- a `InvoiceYear` column (which could totally be computed as `YEAR(InvoiceDate)`)
- an `InvoiceID INT IDENTITY` column which you could reset every year to 1
- create a computed column `InvoiceNumber` as:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE dbo.InvoiceTable
     ADD InvoiceNumber AS CAST(InvoiceYear AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' +
             RIGHT('000000' + CAST(InvoiceID AS VARCHAR(6)), 6) PERSISTED
  ```

This way, you automagically get invoice numbers:

```
2010-000001
......
2010-001234
......
2010-123456
```

Of course, if you need more than 6 digits (= 1 million invoices) - just adjust the `RIGHT()` and `CAST()` statements for the `InvoiceID` column.

Also, since this is a **persisted** computed column, you can index it for fast retrieval.

This way: **you** don't have to worry about concurrency, stored procs, transactions and stuff like that - SQL Server will do that for you - for free!

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not enough. The shared lock set by the select will not prevent anyone from reading that same value at the same time.

Change this:

```
select @maxNum = MAX(SequenceNumber) from invoice where YEAR = @year
```

To this:

```
select @maxNum = MAX(SequenceNumber) from invoice with (updlock, holdlock) where YEAR = @year
```

This way you replace the shared lock with an update lock, and two update locks are not compatible with each over.
The `holdlock` means that the lock is to be held until the end of the transaction. So you do still need the transaction bit.

Note that this will not help if there's some other procedure that also wants to do the update. If that other procedure reads the value without providing the `updlock` hint, it will still be able to read the previous value of the counter. This may be a good thing, as it improves concurrency in scenarios where the other readers do not intend to make an update later, but it also may be not what you want, in which case either update all procedures to use `updlock`, or use `xlock` instead to place an exclusive lock, not compatible with shared locks.

Comment: What about just simply using a `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` for this transaction ?? That would exclusively lock anything that gets selected, until the transaction is committed or rolled back...

Comment: @marc_s: Yes, at which point the concurrency might get worse than it could be overwise. I prefer to only use the minimum required set of locks. If there are people who ought to read the value but have no intention to change it, I'm not pissing them off.

Comment: @marc_s: do you have to do that before or after the start transaction statement?

Comment: @Gserg: there is also one other process updating this table. If i fire that procedure when this procedure holds its lock, does the other one wait (a little while) for this lock to end, or does it die once it sees this lock?

Comment: @Gserg: i don't know a lot about locks, but does the 'updlock' prevent the other person running this same procedure from reading `(select @maxNum = MAX(SequenceNumber) from invoice where YEAR = @year )`? and if so, how long will the other procedure wait for the lock to end? Is there a sort of a queue for other procedures waiting for the other one to release their lock?

Comment: @Gserg: sorry for the load of questions, but what does the `updlock` lock? does it lock all the rows `where YEAR = @year` or does it lock the whole table or only the row which contains the `Max(sequencenumber)`?

Comment: @Michel: you have to set the transaction isolation level **BEFORE** the BEGIN TRANSACTION - otherwise it doesn't have any effect

Comment: @marc_s: can you explain what 'everyting' is in 'That would exclusively lock anything that gets selected'

Comment: @Michel: any rows that get selected are locked until the end of the transaction.

Comment: @Michel: I think in that case you really should read up on locks before developing an application that stores data for 10 years. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039.aspx) shoud be a good place to start, and, obviuosly, get familiar with the [SQL Server Books Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx) as a whole.